# CrossRider - when do we need to use appAPI.JSON?

Tags: crossrider

When do we need to use `appAPI.JSON.stringify` and `appAPI.JSON.parse` and why not use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` instead? Is there a difference between `appAPI.JSON` and `JSON` in some browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [appAPI.JSON.stringify](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.JSON-method-stringify) and [appAPI.JSON.parse](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.JSON-method-parse) methods are provided to support for these JSON methods in older browsers that do not natively support JSON.stringify and JSON.parse (e.g. IE7). Hence, it's a good practice to use them from the outset.

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]